# Spring boot feign client is not decrypting cipher value

Tags: spring-boot, java-8

I have a `Spring Boot` Application where in `application.yml` file I have below property

```
password: '{cipher}hdjfhjksdkfhsdfhfsdjfhshfh'
```

I am using this property in `feign client` as. -

```
@FeignClient(name = "employee-client", url = "${employee.url}"    ,
    configuration = EmployeeFeignConfiguration.class)
 public interface EmployeeClient {

@GetMapping(value = "/employee", headers = {"password=${employee.password}",
        "accept=application/json"}, produces=APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
List<EmployeeResponse> employees(@RequestParam("emplIds") List<String> emplIds);
}
```

I have also configured `ENCRYPT_KEY` in `bootstrap.yml` file.

But in `feign client header`, password is always `cipher` value and not `decrypted` one, see below log

```
[EmployeeClient#employees] password: hdjfhjksdkfhsdfhfsdjfhshfh
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.